# Extract data from a web with Goutte when the data is loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, extract, goutte

Im trying to extract the data of these products [https://www.appliancesdelivered.ie/search?sort=price_desc#/?search_return=all&sort_by_field=Price+Low+to+High](https://www.appliancesdelivered.ie/search?sort=price_desc#/?search_return=all&sort_by_field=Price%20Low%20to%20High).

I'm using Laravel and Goutte for this, but i cant make it work... When i try to extract the menu header works fine...

[with menu header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfkvH.png)

```
$products = $crawler->filter('body > div.container > header > nav > ul > li > a')->each(function ($node) {
        print $node->text()."\n";
        return $node->text();
});
dd($products);
```

Now when a tried to get the title of the products in te list for test purpose (using the same way of select path) the result is a null array...

```
$products = $crawler->filter('body > div.container >div > div.product-popup-container > div.container > div > div.search-results.col-md-9 > div > div.product-description.col-xs-8.col-sm-8 > div > div.col-xs-12.col-sm-7.col-lg-8 > h4 > a')->each(function ($node) {
        print $node->text()."\n";
        return $node->text();
});
dd($products);
```

I am starting to think that it may be because the list of products is loaded with ajax and it is not obtained from the first request as it happens with the header menu ... What can I do to extract the information correctly? help please!

Comment: if that is the case you would probably need a headless browser, as you would need something that can actually run the js. selenium is an option.

Comment: How would that be? How about an implementation that allows me to pause the execution of the extraction until the entire web has been fully loaded?

Comment: its not going to be 'loaded'. this isn't a web browser. it makes a request with guzzle and then parses that html. there is no rendering happening. goutte uses dom crawler which understands the structure of html/xml documents. you would need something like a web browser to render html or execute the javascript.